# How to read next 6 lines and print it out from text file

Tags: c++, file, text

I'm defining an "Edit" function in which user enters in the ID, and i'm looking forward to print out the next 13 lines, and make changes to them, the data's are now stored in the text file like this :

```
      6663  : available
      pouya
      oyya
      3
      2
      3
      4
      3
      2
      3
      1
      2
      3
      4
      7897  : available
      pouya
      pouya
      3
      4
      . 
      .
      .
```

So I could write a function to search for the entered id, and it works, but I don't know how to define a way, in which these fields can be printed out and edited ... here is my function :

```
    void Edit_the_apartment(string pass) {

    std::fstream ifile("apartment.txt", std::ios::binary);
    ifile.seekg(0, std::ios_base::end);
    long s = ifile.tellg();
    char *buffer = new char[s];
    ifile.seekg(0);
    ifile.read(buffer, s);
    ifile.close();
    std::string txt(buffer, s);
    delete[] buffer;
    size_t off = 0;
    while ((off = txt.find(pass, off)) != std::string::npos)
    {


        //// Print next 13 lines and make changes to it 


    }

}
```

the logic is whenever the user enters in the ID, value will be searched within the file, and the next 13 lines will be printed which are the details related to the same apartment ID, therefore user can edit the save new data.

Comment: Is it a console application? Pretty hard to achieve text editing in console. Maybe some GUI will be better in this case.

Comment: @PavelOganesyan you are too young for that, but I learned programming with just a teletype (yes almost a typing machine ...) to edit source programs. There are still `ed` and `ex` in Linux to be used as examples ... but I must admit I do prefer using `vi` or any IDE !

Comment: yes, it is a console application, and i'm not willingly be able to change it.... as it required by the case study ....